# Is there encoding in Unicode where every "character" is just one code point?

Tags: unicode, normalization, utf-16, unicode-normalization, surrogate-pairs

Trying to rephrase: Can you map every combining character combination into one code point?

I'm new to Unicode, but it seems to me that there is no encoding, normalization or representation where one character would be one code point in every case in Unicode. Is this correct?

Is this true for Basic Multilingual Plane also?

Comment: Every Unicode "character" is just one "code point". The terminology can be confusing though. "Character" can be interpreted in various ways so Unicode came up with the term "code point" to cover one specific sense of "character". Now a "glyph" can be made up of more than one "code point" and a "code point" can be encoded as more than once "code unit". In UTF-8 a "code unit" is 8 bits and in UTF-16 a "code unit" is 16 bits. In UTF-32 (rarely used) there is no need to distinguish between "code points" and "code units" but even then you can make a single "glyph" out of a multiple "code points".

Comment: @hippietrail Do you mean *character* the *abstract character* in the Unicode [spec section 3.4](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch03.pdf#G2212)? I am asking this because I am confusing…

Comment: @Eonil: I firstly mean *character* = *code point* and secondly mean *character* = *glyph*. Which of the two are you asking about?

Comment: @hippietrail Actually I asked for it to get some insight about what *abstract character* is. The concept repeatedly shown in the the doc, but I really can't what actually it is… And you seem to know what those are.

Comment: Actually I find their terminology in their own documentation pretty difficult to read, so I feel your pain. My comment is based on my own knowledge built up over the years, rather than taken straight from Unicode's docs.

Comment: Note that the term "encoding" does not belong to the question as it happens well after the mapping between abstract characters and their code points. The encodings use code units which are then serialized into bytes.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean one char == one number (ie: where every char is represented by the same number of bytes/words/what-have-you): in UCS-4, each character is represented by a 4-byte number.  That's way more than big enough for every character to be represented by a single value, but it's quite wasteful if you don't need any of the higher chars.

If you mean the compatibility sequences (ie: where e + ´ => é): there are single-character representations for most of the combinations in use in existing modern languages.  If you're making up your own language, you could run into problems...but if you're sticking to the ones that people actually use, you'll be fine.

Comment: Can I get the 100% mapping guarantee also into NFC normalization form?

Comment: There is no 100% mapping guarantee.  It just happens that there are code points representing precomposites of the combinations you'll see in modern languages.  NFC will prefer those precomposites in most cases.  But if you have a character and accent that don't typically go together (for example, `z̏`), or have a bunch of accents for one character, one code point ain't gonna cut it.

Comment: This just isn't true. There's plenty of combinations in use in existing modern languages with no single-character representations. Especially in scripts other than Latin such as Indic scripts, Thai, Lao, etc. I would regard the Cyrillic vowels with acute accents as pretty common since they're in pretty much every Russian dictionary, yet they do not have single codepoint representations.

Comment: @hippietrail: That's...pretty specific.  But i'm noticing that Cyrillic letters with *other* types of accents do indeed have single-character forms -- which hints that the Unicode Consortium didn't consider the acute accent common enough in Cyrillic to warrant the use of code points.  When are acute accents used outside of a dictionary?

Comment: Unicode apparently does not base it on "common enough". Ideally they don't want any new precomposed characters. They say they want to be compatible with legacy encodings so they include almost all precomposed characters in commonly used legacy encodings but strongly resist any new ones. I'm pretty sure I heard they even resisted the precomposed Vietnamese Latin characters and precomposed Hangul (Korean) syllables, but caved into pressure to include them. Unfortunately I don't have any references, this is from memory from following Unicode with varying interest levels since the '90s.+1)

Comment: I personally don't see a good reason for precomposing at all, if they ignore legit combinations that exist in real languages.  The only thing it's really good for these days is making storage space requirements more predictable, and that doesn't work when you still can't trust a char to take up a char's worth of space.  IMO, the solution causes more problems than it fixes.

Answer (score 6):

> Can you map every combining character
>   combination into one code point?

*Every* combining character combination?  How would your proposed encoding represent the string "à̴̵̶̷̸̡̢̧̨̛̖̗̘̙̜̝̞̟̠̣̤̥̦̩̪̫̬̭̮̯̰̱̲̳̹̺̻̼͇͈͉͍͎́̂̃̄̅̆̇̈̉̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔̽̾̿̀́͂̓̈́͆͊͋͌̕̚ͅ͏͓͔͕͖͙͚͐͑͒͗͛ͣͤͥͦͧͨͩͪͫͬͭͮͯ͘͜͟͢͝͞͠͡"?  (an 'a' with more than a hundred combining marks attached to it?)  It's just not practical.

There are, however, a lot of "precomposed" characters in Unicode, like áçñü.  Normalization form C will use these instead of the decomposed version whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

> it seems to me that there is no encoding, normalization or representation where one character would be one code point in every case in Unicode. Is this correct?

Depends on the meaning of the meaning of the word “character.” Unicode has the concepts of *abstract character* (definition 7 in chapter 3 of the standard: “A unit of information used for the organization, control, or representation of textual data”) and *encoded character* (definition 11: “An association (or mapping) between an abstract character and a code point”). So a character never *is* a code point, but for many code points, there exists an abstract character that maps to the code point, this mapping being called “encoded character.” But (definition 11, paragraph 4): “A single abstract character may also be *represented* by a sequence of code points”

> Is this true for Basic Multilingual Plane also?

There is no conceptual difference related to abstract or encoded characters between the BMP and the other planes. The statement above holds for all subsets of the codespace.

Depending on your application, you have to distinguish between the terms *glyph*, *grapheme cluster*, *grapheme*, *abstract character*, *encoded character*, *code point*, *scalar value*, *code unit* and *byte*. All of these concepts are different, and there is no simple mapping between them. In particular, there is almost never a one-to-one mapping between these entities.