# how to calculate length of characters when text can have non latin letters

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have function that display ASCII table in monospace font

```
        function ascii_table(array, header) {
            if (!array.length) {
                return '';
            }

            for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var row = array[i];
                var stacks = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
                    var new_lines = row[j].toString().split("\n");
                    row[j] = new_lines.shift();
                    stacks.push(new_lines);
                }
                var new_rows_count = Math.max.apply(Math, stacks.map(function(column) {
                    return column.length;
                }));
                for (var k = new_rows_count - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
                    array.splice(i + 1, 0, stacks.map(function(column) {
                        return column[k] || "";
                    }));
                }
            }

            var lengths = array[0].map(function(_, i) {
                var col = array.map(function(row) {
                    if (row[i] != undefined) {
                        return row[i].length;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                });
                return Math.max.apply(Math, col);
            });
            // column padding
            array = array.map(function(row) {
                return '| ' + row.map(function(item, i) {
                    var size = item.length;
                    if (size < lengths[i]) {
                        if (item.match(/\t/g)) {
                            // tab have 4 spaces
                            size += item.match(/\t/g).length*3;
                        }
                        item += new Array(lengths[i] - size + 1).join(' ');
                    }
                    return item;
                }).join(' | ') + ' |';
            });
            var sep = '+' + lengths.map(function(length) {
                return new Array(length + 3).join('-');
            }).join('+') + '+';
            if (header) {
                return sep + '\n' + array[0] + '\n' + sep + '\n' +
                    array.slice(1).join('\n') + '\n' + sep;
            } else {
                return sep + '\n' + array.join('\n') + '\n' + sep;
            }
        }
```

but fail if table cell contain japanese letters like `中文` when one character have width of two ascii letters:

```
中文
rock
```

How can I deal with cases like this? How can I know if width of a character have size of two?

Comment: That would depend on the font you use for rendering it.

Comment: You seem to two issues here: `length` returns the number of UTF-16 code units, one or two encode a Unicode codepoint, one or more compose to form a grapheme; and, a font that doesn't use the same width for all scripts. (Since a grapheme could theoretically have an arbitrarily large number of combining codepoints, a monospace font can't represent all graphemes in the same width, anyway. Non-real-world [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4611941/2226988). )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to check the characters *width* rather than length. Anything that is a (decent) [port](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/wcwidth) of [wcwidth](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wcswidth.3.html) should do the trick.

Comment: I've tested that function on https://www.codechef.com/ide and it return -1 for `wcswidth("中文", 2)`

Comment: Not sure which one you were trying, but with https://www.npmjs.com/package/wcwidth I have `var wcwidth = require('wcwidth'); console.log(wcwidth('中文'));` printing `4`, which is the correct width (2 full-width characters).

Comment: I've used C version need to check that npm module.